# Изменение порядка элементов списка, согласно заданному

Tags: python

Как сделать весь этот код в одну строчку?

```py
    list_x = [1,2,3,8]
    sequence = [2,1,4,3]

    result = [0,0,0,0]
    j = 0
    for i in sequence:
        result[j] = list_x[i-1]
        j+=1

    print(result)
```

Ожидаемый результат: `[2, 1, 8, 3]`

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 7):

[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
In [99]: res = [list_x[i-1] for i in sequence]

In [100]: res
Out[100]: [2, 1, 8, 3]
```